# Do modules have any topology?

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, modules

Is there any kind of topology, natural or unnatural, that modules do have? Is there any geometric interpretation for flat modules? Is "exactness" of a sequence, any kind of geometric condition? Thanks.

Comment: Sure: every module carries the discrete topology, and also the indiscrete topology. But this is not a particularly useful observation.

Comment: the Krull-toplogy, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(ring_theory

Comment: @QiaochuYuan surely, but any kind of interesting topology, I mean, not the trivial one.

Comment: @Blah dead link

Comment: All you have to do is add ')' at the end of the link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(ring_theory)

Comment: @Jr.: If your base is noetherian and your module is finitely generated, flat modules are the same thing as locally free modules, so you can think of a flat module as being something like a vector bundle. But exactness is very much algebraic.

Comment: You can put a Zariski topology on the set of prime submodules of $M$ if $M$ is a multiplication module.